# c# - Building an object that might contains null ref

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

i'm trying to build an object with below attribute

```
    public class data
    {
        public string Ref{ get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public string Type{ get; set; }
        public string? Origin{ get; set; }

    };
```

Thing is that : ref / Number / Type, i'll be sure to find those data in my XML file, but Origin might be null in some cases.

Below code is looped via some elt in a XML file, some times we can find origin in a collection of subelement, sometimes origin cannot be found since there is no subelement matching condition.

How can I handle this null exception while still building my object ? The goal is to have an Origin = "" if it cannot be found.

```
           containerData.Add(new dataContainer()
            {
                Ref= elt.Descendants(ns + "Ref")
                      .FirstOrDefault()
                      .Value,

                Number = elt.Descendants(ns+"Number")
                         .FirstOrDefault()
                         .Value,

                Type = elt.Descendants(ns + "Type")
                         .FirstOrDefault()
                         .Value,

                Origin = subElement.Where(x => x.Element(ns + "Name").Value == "Origin")
                                .Select(x => x.Element(ns + "Value"))
                                .SingleOrDefault()
                                .Value,

            });
```

trying to get Origin nullable type, but object still throwing me exception when building.

Comment: _"throwing me exception when building"_ then it's a compiler error, not an exception. What does it say?

Comment: ... and have you tried `.SingleOrDefault()?.Value ?? ""` ?

Comment: it was that simple ... thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.SingleOrDefault()` may return `null`, so you may guard against that with `.SingleOrDefault()?.Value` (=> Only access `Value` if not null).

This leaves you with a value or `null`. If you want to have an empty string in that case (if `null`), you can use `.SingleOrDefault()?.Value ?? ""`.

For reference:

- [Null-conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)
- [null-coalescing-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)